# How can I resize/zoom a complex JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jfreechart

I have a complex JFrame. It has a main panel in absoluteLayout, which has buttons and labels, a couple of jFreeCharts and a second(sub) panel with a specific GridLayout, which I fill with multiple labels.

Is there anyway to resize/zoom the whole thing?

```
pack() does not work because of the layout.
```

Is there a more rudimentary "ScaleTheWholeWindow" approach?

Comment: You can loop through all elements in your jframe, multiply their position values and size values by some factor. Then recursively do the same for each container in the frame. The problem with this, is that you're going to get non-whole numbers. You may want to think about how to solve that.

At the end of the day, swing is layout based. You shouldn't really use an absolute layout.

Comment: Don't use AbsoluteLayout!

Comment: @camickr But if I don't use AbsoluteLayout - how can I get a screen to look how I want it to?

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Don't forget you can use different layout managers on every panel to achieve your desired layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for my comment would look `something` like this. I didn't test this, this is more an idea. Easier to articulate my idea with code.

```
public void scaleContainer(Container c, double xFactor, double yFactor)
{
    Component[] eles = c.getComponents();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < eles.length ; i++)
    {
        eles[i].setBounds(new Rectangle(
             (int) eles[i].getX() * xFactor, 
             (int) eles[i].getY() * yFactor, 
             (int) eles[i].getWidth() * xFactor, 
             (int) eles[i].getHeight() * yFactor))
        if(eles[i] instanceof Container)
        {
            if(((Container)eles[i]).getLayout() == null) //If the container has it's own layout, let it assign it's own components
                scaleContainer((Conatiner)eles[i], xFactor, yFactor);
        }
    }
}
```

**If you want to scale by a fixed number of pixels, and not a factor, then you need to calculate the factor. The factor would be `1 + (extraWidth / previousWidth)`(and similar for height)**

Comment: This looks promising to me. How do I know when & by how much the Frame size has changed? i.e. when it has been made bigger?

Comment: You'll want to operate on the panel that's inside the frame. Not sure how a frame behaves with setBounds. In any case. Given a container c you can do `x = c.getWidth(); scaleContainer(c, 1.5, 1.5); dx = c.getWidth() - x`

Comment: You should also realise that, this will not scale the text size of your labels, so they may look awkward after resizing.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a way to do it as you are asking but a better approach would be to have functions that set each of your elements widths/heights to percentages of the current width/height and that way you will always get the same layout rather than the rudimentary one you have asked for.